# How to get posted data

Tags: php, post

I am new in php so maybe my question is quite easy. Let's say that I have the following

**index.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
<form name="quiz" method="post" action="includes/process.php">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname"/><span>*</span>
<p></p>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname"/><span>*</span>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and I want to post the data to the next page then:

**process.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Form Post</title>
<body>
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 
echo "my name is $firstname<br/>";
echo "my lastname is $lastname<br/>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my question is how can I get again the data of the process.php and post them to an another php page or maybe to save them in a mysql database? Is there any tutorial of how to get or use posted data?

Comment: You could use sessions.

Comment: When you GOOGLE `PHP form data post` you get nothing? Or `PHP mysql save`?

Comment: You could do what Fred said above or pass them along to the next page with a link
<a href="nextpage.php?firstname=<?php echo $firstname ?>&lastname=<?php echo $lastname ?>" target="_blank">nextpage</a> and fetch the data again with $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

Comment: @Malcolm that way, you would get them through `$_GET` array.

Comment: @moonwave99 that's true :)

Comment: If sessions are going to be used, then `session_start();` must be the first line (99% of the time) and in ALL files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **Sessions** to store the data.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'])) {
// Store session data
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname'];
}
?>
```

And then to fetch the data back again.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
// Get session data
$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
$lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
echo $firstname;
echo $lastname;
}
?>
```

Or pass it along with a link

```
<a href="nextpage.php?firstname=<?php echo $firstname ?>&lastname=<?php echo $lastname ?>" >nextpage</a>
```

And then to fetch the data back again

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['firstname'], $_GET['lastname'])) {
// Get variables passed with link
$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
echo $firstname;
echo $lastname;
}
?>
```

Comment: In your example with sessions when I fetch the data then again I must add session_start();? Because you do not have it as I can see.

Comment: Remember, `session_start();` must be the first line, 99% of the time and in ALL files.

Comment: @dali1985 See my comment above this one, important.